# Getting error Entrypoint html-webpack-plugin for "index.html" = index.html when set my webpack config file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have started learning react js, but I am stucked in setting my webpackconfig.file.I am getting below error:

```
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
 1 asset
Entrypoint html-webpack-plugin for "index.html" = index.html
```

webpack config file:

```
        const path = require('path');
        const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

        module.exports = {
                          entry: './src/main.js',
                          output: {
                                   path.join(__dirname, '/bundle'),
                                   filename: 'index_bundle.js'
                                  },
                           devServer: {
                                   inline: true,
                                   port: 8080
                                  },
                           module: {
                                     rules: [
                                                {
                                                  test: /\.jsx?$/,
                                                  exclude: /node_modules/,
                                                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                                                  query: {
                                                           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                                                   }
                                                 }
                                               ]
                                         },
                             plugins:[
                                      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                                      template: './index.html'
                                      })
                                     ]
                          }
```

By searching, It might be problem in webpackplugins

package.json file:

```
    {                
      "name": "reactApp",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
                  "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
                  "build": "webpack --mode production"
   },
   "keywords": [],
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
                     "react": "^16.7.0",
                     "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
                     "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
                     "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.7",
   "webpack": "^4.28.1"
}
```

My each and every file(index.html,main.js,pacage.json,webpacconfig.js,.babelrc) is in a same folder, I can't detect what the actual problem,

Comment: Can you please provide a little bit more information about an error? Because I don't see any useful information in your logs.

Comment: You're saying your main.js is in same folder as of webpack config. But the config mentions src/main.js as entry point. Are you sure your index.html is in same folder as of webpack config and not in src/ directory?